# Open file from same directory

Tags: ruby, siri

Ok so with siriproxy it my lib folder along with the rb file for the plugin I have created a myconfig.yml file so I can change certain settings by writing to that file.

I have been able to write to the file but only if I include the full path all the way from the home directory down.

But is there not a way to open the file from the same directory i am in? I have tried every path combination I can think of.

There has to be one i am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the following in your ruby file, you should get the absolute path where it is

```
File.expand_path(__FILE__)
```

From [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__FILE__) `__FILE__`

> The name of the file currently being executed, including path relative to the directory where the application was started up (or the current directory, if it has been changed)

From [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path) `File.expand_path`

> Converts a pathname to an absolute pathname.

As you probably want the directory, you should use `File.dirname(__FILE__)`, so the path of your file `myconfig.yml` should be obtained with

```
File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'myconfig.yml')
```

In more recent Ruby (>=2.0.0), you can use [`__dir__`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) (from Archonic's comment):

> Returns the canonicalized absolute path of the directory of the file from which this method is called. It means symlinks in the path is resolved. If **FILE** is nil, it returns nil. The return value equals to File.dirname(File.realpath(**FILE**)).

Comment: `File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))` can be replaced with `__dir__` in more recent ruby versions (tested on 2.5.3)